# Fetching a summary grouped by month with Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table called `gk` and I am currently running two queries. Please have a look at the queries:

```
Gk::groupBy(DB::raw("MONTH(created_at)"))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw("YEAR(created_at)"))
    ->selectRaw('id, user_id, sum(ton) as ton,pl, count(id) as total, sum(w) , created_at')
    ->with(array('user'=> function($q){
          $q->select('id', 'userName', 'profilePic');
    }))
    ->where('user_id', $userData[0]->id)
    ->get();
```

This query returns a little summary of every months. As you can I see I am grouping results by months and years. And I have another query which will return all the rows of any given months. 
I am running second query like this

```
 $m=Carbon::parse($request->date);
 Gk::where('user_id',$request->user_id)->whereRaw(DB::raw("YEAR(created_at)=$m->year"))->whereRaw(DB::raw("MONTH(created_at)=$m->month"))
   ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
   ->get();
```

The second query returns all the rows of any month. I'm executing this query in a foreach loop for all of the months that are returned in the first query.

I am trying to combine this two query into one so that I can get a group of the results by months and years and also all the details of that month.

Any help, suggestions or idea would be extremely helpful.

[Note: For the date in second query, this date is `created_at` result from the first query.]

Thank you.

Comment: Not a single one of [stock methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#available-methods) help you out? Or combination of...

Comment: HI, thank you for such a nice learning resource. I am trying with it currently still trying to figure it out.. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Yea, no problem; before asking try as hard as you can to solve it yourself, its much more rewarding then just +5 / +10 you get for asking a good question. Use `php artisan tinker`, craft simple collections and play with them first or just write a failing test and try to make it not fail.

Comment: Thank you so much again I am trying it for 48 hours :( 
Hope I will get something. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I read your question is as following: The second query is executed in a loop with results from the first one. Is that right? In my answer I have explained a way to execute the second query just one time instead of in a loop. You'd still have to execute the first query once.

So, I think that you are better of using the Php collection methods:

```
$results = Gk::where('user_id',$request->user_id)
    ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function (Gk $item) {
        return $item->created_at->format('Y-m');
    });
```

The `groupBy` method has to return an attribute on which you want to group the elements. For this example I think that using a `yyyy-mm` format will do fine.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-groupby

*Edit: Maybe you can also get rid of the orderBy method call because you are grouping by afterwards:*

```
$results = Gk::where('user_id',$request->user_id)
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function (Gk $item) {
        return $item->created_at->format('Y-m');
    });
```

*Edit 2: To combine the information of the two queries, you could do something like the following:*

```
$results = Gk::where('user_id',$request->user_id)
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function (Gk $item) {
        return $item->created_at->format('Y-m');
    })->map(function(Collection $rows) {
        return [
            'sum(ton)' => $rows->sum('ton'),
            'total' => $rows->count(),
            'sum(w)' => $rows->sum('w'),
            'rows' => $rows
        ];
    );
```

Note that I have omitted a few of the selected columns in your first query because they are not unique in the given group by. But feel free to add any logic in the map function. Because we use `map()` after `groupBy`, every call of `map()` will receive a collection of items for one month. You can that use that fabulous collection magic to calculate all values that you need and reduce the number of queries to just one.

Comment: This is a nice solution and works nicely but it doesn't give me a summary of the month like for example in my first query you can see I have some aggregate functions. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I've updated my anwer. I think that you will have to keep that first query there. With just 2 single queries that don't repeat you don't have to worry about performance for the most applications. You can combine those pieces of information in php with collection methods or just within a for loop when you are displaying the information.

Comment: So you mean I have to run the first query separately and then combine the result using collection method like marge() ?

Comment: Yeah, I'll think about an example to update my answer. I don't think `merge()` is the method you need for this.

Comment: Oh, while I'm writing I noticed that you could maybe reduce it to one query.

Comment: That would be awesome. I was thinking for a nested collections as I use vue js for iterating over objects.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I did ;) I moved the calculations of the first query to php.

Comment: Haha, and i made my mind if query cannot help I can achieve it simply by javascript. But still curious if that is possible in eloquent query for two reason. 1. I can learn it and others 2. Work is simplified

Comment: Well, it is as you can see in my answer :)

Comment: Thank you, I marked this answer as correct as it solved 90% problems. 
Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi. please help for one last time. Your last updated answer gives this error 
`Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\MemberController::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Collection, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given`

Comment: Ok solved it. I need to pass $result like this `->map(function($result )`

This answer has solved my problem 100% 

:)

Comment: If you want to typehint the `$result` parameter you have to import the eloquent collection class.